# Batch replacing Visual Studio Solution identifiers

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

I need to replace some identifiers in my solution, to avoid conflicts with external dependencies.

I used the Find and Replace dialog, setting the `Entire solution` as scope. It works, but it is too long.
One possibility could be:

```
 forfiles /s /p path\to\solution  /m *.cpp  /C "sed -i 's/oldid/newid/g' @file"
```

Anyway, I have external include directories located in `path\to\solution`,  which means writing the line above for every project directory (and of course including also `*.h` files).
Instead, VS GUI is smart enough to parse `*.h` and `*.cpp` files, excluding external dependencies.

Is there some (Visual Studio) CLI tool to list solution files, excluding external dependencies?